# What's the shortcut for quickly creating curly braces in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I want to code:

```
if(x == 0) {
   ...
}
```

The problem I have is, after I type 0 as:

```
if(x == 0|)      //'|' is the cursor
```

I have to press left arrow key to let the cursor to get out of the parentheses then type curly braces, but  I don't want to press arrow to move the cursor to the right (out of the brackets) since the arrow key is quite far from the normal keys, I type fast, it is really annoying I have to move my finger that far to access left arrow key and it really slows me.

Is it a way/shortcut to quickly creating curly braces without the need of moving cursor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Text Macros for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=XavierPoinas.TextMacrosforVisualStudio201220132015) extension, applicable for MSVS versions 2012-2019.

Simply download and double click the installation file to install.

Create the Macro as shown in **How does it work?** section in the link. You can then run the created macro by pressing `Ctrl + M`, followed by `1` (or higher number for additional macros).

If needed, the shortcuts may be changed in `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`,  look for commands `Tools.RunSavedMacro1`, `Tools.RunSavedMacro2`, etc.

However, this is not a question for Super User, it should be on Stack Overflow, where you can already find an [extensive thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015-2017-2019).